# What is the optimal AirPlay configuration when using two Airports Express?

Tags: airport, airplay, airtunes

I have two Airport Express base stations in my abode:

- an [AirPort Express 802.11n (2nd Generation) – A1392](http://support.apple.com/kb/SP651), and
- an [AirPort Express 802.11n (1st Generation) – A1264](http://support.apple.com/kb/SP1)

Call the former (the newer model) `A` and the latter `B.` They are in the following configuration: `A` is wired to the cable modem and is the primary wireless base station; `B` is in a different room, configured to join that wireless network, and is connected to a stereo system. The goal of this setup is to provide the fastest possible internet to laptops, iPhones, etc. while enabling AirPlay music streaming to the stereo.

Unfortunately, I can't run a long ethernet cable between rooms (in a practical manner) – though if I could, of course I'd be able to remove one of the base stations from the setup entirely. Naturally, I would also like to keep the two base stations as part of the same wireless network, so I can use the internet while also playing music over AirPlay.

[This Apple Knowledge Base document](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4587) suggests that `B` *joining* `A`'s network (the current configuration) is better than `B` *extending* `A`'s network, for "overhead" reasons:

> **Connecting to an existing Wi-Fi network as part of a legacy WDS or Extended Network**
>
> AirPort Express extends Wi-Fi network range and streams iTunes music simultaneously using Extended Network for AirPort Express with 802.11n, or legacy WDS with AirPort Express 802.11g from another Wi-Fi base station.
>
> Due to the overhead required for this configuration, you may expect AirPlay drop-outs such as intermittent loss of audio.

I'm not sure if that's really an issue since they're both 802.11n routers. Then again, `B` is a "Draft 802.11n" device. I'm not sure how that affects things.

#### Problem

Streaming music from a laptop, regardless of the source (iTunes, Pandora, etc.) tends to stutter, intermittently cutting out for a few seconds. [This](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2703198) [seems](http://www.hometheaterforum.com/topic/322399-here-was-my-fix-to-airplay-intermittent-cutting-out/) to be a [common](http://forums.appleinsider.com/t/119909/airport-express-airtunes-cutting-out) [issue](http://www.ehow.com/info_12229936_buffering-problems-streaming-audio-airport-express.html). I haven't tested whether higher-bitrate songs causes the audio to cut out more frequently.

#### Question

How should I configure my wireless network(s) to reduce, and ideally prevent entirely, the audio from cutting out when I play music to my stereo using AirPlay? All of the hardware involved is Apple-made, so I can only imagine this is not a terribly exotic setup.

I haven't tried swapping the base stations yet. I'm willing to do that, but I'd really prefer to avoid trial-and-error with every combination of physical and software configurations. What can I say – it's not exactly my idea of a fun weekend project.

I *have* tried setting up a 5GHz wireless network on `A`, and having `B` join that, but it doesn't appear that `B` can. It looks like [A1264 can broadcast at 5GHz](http://support.apple.com/kb/SP1), though I don't know if that implies it should be able to join a 5GHz network. Either way, it sure doesn't seem to be able to join *my* 5GHz network.

#### Potentially relevant details

- There is a printer connected to `B` with USB.
- No computers in the room have Bluetooth enabled, though there is an iPhone 5 and Pebble watch that are paired with Bluetooth. I mention this because BT supposedly can cause problems with AirPlay.

Answer (score 1):

Funny story.

Switching `B` from "Join a wireless network" to "Extend a wireless network" seemed to fix the problem instantly, despite the caveat in [that Apple KB doc.](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4587)

[image]

---

Two days later, the problem has returned. It seems that I can deliberately exacerbate the problem by using extra bandwidth, such as by running a [speed test](http://speedtest.net) (over WiFi, of course).